# Calling Wcf service from jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf

I have no knowledge on WCF services. I am from java background. I need to use a `WCF service` i.e. `http://192.168.1.5/xeservices/AccountManagement.svc` with `jquery` and `ajax`.  I don't know how to use it. I have no .net in my system also. From service I found that I should have `svcutils.exe` in ordered to create client. I know, by installing Microsoft SDK I can get it. Please anybody tell me how to achieve my goal.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/132809/Calling-WCF-Services-using-jQuery i just google nd lot of results are there for this . please try them and find any error then post the question here.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/128478/Consuming-WCF-REST-Services-Using-jQuery-AJAX-Call

Comment: You would not need to install anything. You just need to find a way to create a Java class from the wsdl the WCF service returns. There is eclipse plugin to generate java class form wsdl (http://sourceforge.net/projects/wsdl2javawizard/) Try that and hopefully that should be enough for you to consume the WCF Service

Comment: @Rajesh I want to use the service for `andoird` project with `Jquery Mobile` Framework. For that How can I use that generated java class?

Comment: Is it hosted as a RESTful WCF service or SOAP Service or both?

Comment: If its only a SOAP service then you can see this link on how to parse a SOAP xml received as a response from the call : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329322/is-it-possible-to-parse-a-soap-response-with-a-jquery-xml-handler

Comment: @Rajesh Its a SOAP service.

Comment: Did you have a look at the above link on how to parse a SOAP response xml.

Comment: @Rajesh I am not getting any response here. It returns error status as 0

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29912/discussion-between-sudheer-kaju-and-rajesh)

Answer (score 2):

No need to install .Net or its framework, direct use WCF URL using AJAX and Jquery.

Answer (score 1):

If your `WCF Service` is written in such a way, like in the `CodeProject links` in the comments, you can access a `WCF Service` like javascript snippet show in that.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/132809/Calling-WCF-Services-using-jQuery

Answer (score 1):

Try this

For Json Type result

In InterFace

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/ItemGetItem?id={id}", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
[OperationContract]
void  ItemGetItem(string id);
```

In Script

```
self.GetItem= function () {
         try {
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "Your Url",
                 contentType: 'application/json',
                 async: false,
                 dataType: 'json',
                 cache: false,
                 success: function (response) {
                      //Do some stuff here with Data
                 },
                 error: function (ErrorResponse) {
                      //Handle error
                 }
            });
         }
         catch (error) {

         }
     }
```

put endpoint of client application to consume this service