# Quickest way to implement a basic REST/SOAP server and client for a beginner?

Tags: javascript, rest, soap

I would really appreciate some help and also I apologize if this is the incorrect type of question for this site.

Basically, as part of my University coursework I have been tasked with creating a REST/SOAP server and client that allows users to store playlist/song information and update it etc.

My problem however is that all the tutorials provided by the university are for Visual Basic, a program and language that I have yet to learn. Additionally the tutorials seem to consist of "open a new project, copy and paste this code, now run it".

I am aware that REST/SOAP can be implemented in a variety of ways and so I would like to find out what the easiest way for me to learn would be.

I am comfortable with javascript/jquery so any solutions involving those would be preferable. I also wouldn't mind using the opportunity to learn Python if it's feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is great, it has a built in `SoapClient` and is huge in industry as a SOAP/RESTful API language. Anything non-Microsoft will usually use PHP.

As for the client, javascript can very easily work with SOAP objects, as an alternative to SOAP see JSON as a more lightweight communication protocol.

As a starting point, install WAMP if you are on windows, or LAMP on linux and I think MAMP for mac. This sets up a server on your local machine.

Write some php code and run it from your browser to see it spit out raw data. From there you should be able to start learning php basics. http://php.net will have some tutorials.

Regarding the client, check this out it is about jquery processing SOAP responses. [Is it possible to parse a SOAP response with a jQuery xml handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329322/is-it-possible-to-parse-a-soap-response-with-a-jquery-xml-handler)

Comment: Thankyou very much for your response! I will give this a go, PHP is another language I want to learn a lot more about so this is a good opportunity

Comment: I have never met an out of work PHP developer :P