# Javascript SOAP response parse elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, soap

I need to parse a SOAP response xml and display the nodes values in an HTML page in javascript...

The response I've got is the following:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:SOAP-ENC='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance' SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding'><SOAP-ENV:Body><MIA.selPazResponse><statoAnagrafeSiss>ATTIVA</statoAnagrafeSiss><statoAnagrafeAziendale>ATTIVA</statoAnagrafeAziendale><datiCittadino><inserimentoPaz>N</inserimentoPaz><statoAssistito/><idAnag>00000000</idAnag><cognomeCittadino>XXXX</cognomeCittadino><nomeCittadino>YYY</nomeCittadino><sessoCittadino>M</sessoCittadino>codiceFiscaleCittadino>ZZZZ</codiceFiscaleCittadino></MIA.selPazResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I need to get, for example, the tag "cognomeCittadino" and display it in a textform or in a div in the same page! Can anybody help me? I tried with **getElementsByTagName** but it's not working!

Comment: is this in browser or node? in browser you can parse any xml document natively (the browser parses xml for you), in node just require the node-xml module. SOAP is an xml-based format, so if parse xml then you can extract any data from the SOAP message as needed

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Parsing_and_serializing_XML

Comment: I am not that familiar with javascript and soap.. I used to do the same solution with php but in this case I have to make the request in javascript and I got the results directly in the same script.. What I did for getting the code I wrote in my message, is just putting the response in a textarea and I copied and paste here :-D ... What do you think I can do for getting only the tag I need instead of the all response? thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

According to the [DOMParser docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser), it seems it cannot handle SOAP.

Testing your SOAP xml string with the sample code [provided on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Parsing_and_serializing_XML), it returns `parsing error`.

The following solutions seem to work

1. jQuery-based: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8338745/3591273
2. XrmServiceToolkit (from Microsoft): http://xrmservicetoolkit.codeplex.com/ ([reference](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3dfce149-808a-42cf-8019-d54dd46c63d6/parsing-soap-xml-in-js?forum=crmdevelopment))